# How to find all 'SVN working copies' on Win XP

Tags: svn, windows-xp, find

I have Windows XP. I'd like to upgrade my [TortoiseSVN to version 1.7](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html). 
In order to do that I need to ensure that I can find all SVN working copies on my PC. So they can be updated.

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015393/powershell-script-to-find-all-svn-working-copies) but it is specific to Powershell. So, I was wondering if there was a more general solution to find all 'SVN working copies' on Win XP.

If I knew the equivalent of 'linux find' on windows I could probably write it myself. 
But I'm hoping that there may be a bash script out there already (or maybe some solution that's even simpler) that me and others could use.

- scans the computer
- if it finds a directory that contains a directory called ".svn"

  - echo that name, and
  - breaks from searching that directory any more

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you have powershell, I could provide my full script to upgrade working copies to 1.7

```
$prev = "^$"
$workingCopies = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Include ".svn" -Path "d:\Projects\" |?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Fullname.StartsWith($prev)-eq $false} |%{$prev=$_.Fullname.TrimEnd(".svn"); $prev}

foreach($copy in $workingCopies)
{
    &"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" upgrade $copy;
}
```

I dont had issues with access rights to "System Volume" dir (that was just accidentially, cause I store all my sources in one folder I have full rights to..).
As for your issue with Execution Policy - here nice trick to avoid set it forth and back.
You could run powershell with special options to avoid issues with execution policy, user specific profile settings (which could be broken for different reasons) etc:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File “C:\Projects\ConvertSvnToVersion17.ps1”
```

Also I could clarify what exactly this script do (if you are interested):

```
$prev = "^$"
```

Initialize $prev to empty-matching regex - ^$ never match any meaning value (except startline-endline). This was needed to pass initial check

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Include ".svn" -Path "d:\Projects\"
```

Get all objects with name ".svn" (in our case - all files and folders with exact name ".svn"), started from Path, Recursively. 
And pipe it to next construct:

```
?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Fullname.StartsWith($prev)-eq $false}
```

?{...statements... } is shortcut to "Where-Object" cmdlet, $_ is the way to address "each" entry from pipe.
It could be rewritten similar to

```
foreach($entry in $entriesFromSomewhere)
{
    If($entry.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $entry.Fullname.StartsWith($prev) -eq $false)
    {
        "If entry is directory" and  "fullname not start with value from $prev"
        ...Pass entry to next construct...
    }
}
```

But I wrote it as one-liner for the brevity

```
%{$prev=$_.Fullname.TrimEnd(".svn"); $prev}
```

%{} is shortcut for Foreach =)
And this construct doing 2 things :

1. Assign folder fullname without ".svn" tail to $prev
2. Pass $prev further to next pipeline sink.

And entire result set assigned to $workingCopies as array (any result with more than 1 item will be array)

```
foreach($copy in $workingCopies)
{
    &"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" upgrade $copy;
}
```

Foreach element in array - execute command (& sign for "execute as command") "…\svn.exe upgrade "

All the magic here is going to that backtracking $prev element:
On first ".svn" entry $prev contains non-matching value so first check in "where" will be reduced to "If entry is directory". Then assigning step will put folder parent dir. Ex. If found dir fullname is **c:\projects\project1.root\trunk.svn** - $prev will be assigned to ***"c:\projects\project1.root\trunk\"***.
This trick will help us to filter all lower-level .svn dirs:
**c:\projects\project1.root\trunk\SubProject1.svn** entry - will not pass check "not starts with $prev"
And this way we will filter only first level .svn dirs, cause all nested .snv will be filtered by **StartsWith($prev) -eq $false**

So its pretty simple but appears as some magic =)

BTW Thank you for your own answer here - your efforts greatly inspired me to write this comment and clarify entire script.

Grammar geeks should be summoned to this comment for cleaning and rephrasing my "so-called-English"  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to give a detailed explanation. Knowing that _?{...statements... } is shortcut to "Where-Object" cmdlet_ and  _%{} is shortcut for Foreach_ were the keys to understanding it for me. Would you mind if I edited your answer to move my answer into yours to merge it into one?

Comment: I dont mind =) you can do and "vice versa" - edit your and add my clarifications to your answer =)

Comment: Either way, I'll have to do it later cos I have to venture out into the real World soon. :o)

Answer (score 1):

For complex and powerful searches on Windows-box I can recommend (I use it in real-life)

- Embedded search inside Total Commander (your have fair evaluation time)
- GrepWin (with wildcard- and regexp-keywords for filenames patterns)

You miss the point. SVN-clients 1.7 can (and really must) upgrade existing working copies **after installing** before usage. Also nore: **all dirs** inside WC for pre-1.6 versions have .svn dirs, you are interested in only *every top-most*

And later it may be useful for you

1.6 svn-dir

```
.svn>dir /B
all-wcprops
entries
prop-base
props
text-base
tmp
```

1.7 svn-dir

```
.svn>dir /B
entries
format
pristine
tmp
wc.db
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't think I've missed the point that much. If you have to find the working copies after the upgrade and before usage then its still a good idea to find them before even beginning the upgrade process (don't want to be in limbo). Yes I'd agree I am "interested in only every top-most". I think this 'answer' ought to be a 'comment', though.

Comment: Ahha!. I geddit you think the question is mainly about spotting the difference between 1.6 and 1.7 svn dir structures. Whereas I am focusing on 'how to find' them. I'll tweak the question some more.

Comment: @JW. - I think "slightly forward", when you'll *may have a mix* of 1.7 and pre-1.7 WCs.

Comment: Yes. I see. Q is modified. Also I've just checked the [release notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html) and it still implies that you should find them before the upgrade to 1.7: "To be on the safe side, you should run a cleanup with your pre-1.7 svn client on all your working copies, because if the working copy is in an inconsistent state the upgrade process might fail. Best to run cleanup before installing the new version of TortoiseSVN. "

Comment: @JW. - find only for cleanup. I had my WCs in clean state (in one location anyway) and discover mandatory upgrade only after blind update of my TSVN. Nothing terrible happened anyway

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find all 'SVN working copies' on Win XP.

I did it using the [PowerSell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016024/205814) provided by Alexey Shcherbak.

Here is a summary of the process using *the PowerShell method*.

### Test to see if you have PowerShell already installed.

Windows PowerShell is a command-line shell and scripting environment that brings the power of the .NET Framework to command-line users and script writers.

Test to see if it is already installed by attempting to start it.

To start Windows PowerShell from the Run box, click **Start**, click **Run**, and type:

```
powershell
```

If that does not work...

### Install it

- Download *Microsoft Windows PowerShell 1.0 for Windows XP* from [Cnet.com](http://www.cnet.com/)
- (PowerShell 2 for Windows XP is also available, but I did not use it. ([instructions here](http://mintywhite.com/vista/vmaintenance/install-powershell-20-windows-xp/)) )

Once its installed...

### Start PowerShell and have a play

**Start** > **All Programs** > **Windows PowerShell 1.0** > **Windows PowerShell**

[See a brief introduction to PowerShell on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv0ZpVfKiRs&feature=player_embedded).

### Create a PowerShell script

Copy Alexey Shcherbak's [PowerSell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016024/205814) (that finds the svn working copies) into a text file and save it as something like `C:\PowerShellScripts\FindSvnWorkingDirectories.ps1`.

I modified it slightly to search my C drive and to suppress *access denied* errors :

```
$prev = "^$"

Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Force -Include ".svn" -Path "c:\" `
| ?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Fullname.StartsWith($prev)-eq $false}`
| %{ $prev=$_.Fullname.TrimEnd(".svn"); $prev}
```

To explain what this script does in detail:

`$prev = "^$"` initialises `$prev` to empty-matching regex; `^$` will never match any meaningful value (except startline-endline). This was needed to pass initial check.

```
Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Force -Include ".svn" -Path "c:\" `
```

Gets all objects with name ".svn" (in our case - all files and folders with exact name ".svn"), started from Path, Recursively.

- `Get-ChildItem`, by default, is an alias of the `dir` command.
- `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` - Prevents showing errors such as *Access to the path 'C:\System Volume Information' is denied* [as described here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_erroraction_silentlycontinue.htm).
- `-Recurse` means search recusively.
- `-Force` ensures hidden files are found.
- `-Include ".svn"` identifies the filename that we are searching for.
- `-Path "c:\"` idientifies the path to search.
- ` The backtick means [continue the statement to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235993/205814).

On the next line:

```
| ?{$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Fullname.StartsWith($prev)-eq $false}`
```

The pipe symbol, `|`, pipes the output of `Get-ChildItem` into the next cmdlets.

`?{...statements... }` is shorthand for the [`Where-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) cmdlet.

`$_ is` the way to address "each" entry from pipe. It basically says "If entry is a directory" and  "fullname does not start with value from $prev", then "Pass entry to next construct".

```
| %{ $prev=$_.Fullname.TrimEnd(".svn"); $prev}
```

The entry is then piped to the next statement.

`%{}` is shorthand for [`Foreach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx). This construct does 2 things:

- Assign the current folder's fullname to `$prev` (without the ".svn" tail).
- Pass `$prev` to the next pipeline sink.

### Allow PowerShell to run the script

By default, for security, PowerShell's `ExecutionPolicy` does not let you run PowerShell scripts. So, you need to allow it to do so.

See [Running Windows PowerShell Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) for more info.

I did the following:

Note: The hash symbol (#) is just shotrthand for the command prompt.

Determine the current `ExecutionPolicy`:

```
# Get-ExecutionPolicy
Restricted
```

If, like mine, its *Restricted*. Change the policy to allow a script to run:

```
# Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

### Run the PowerShell script

Then run the script to find the svn working copies. Note you need to specify the *full path* to the PowerShell script.

```
# C:\PowerShellScripts\FindSvnWorkingDirectories.ps1
```

If there are loads of directories on the PC it may take some time. The results should appear.

### *Copy and Paste* the results to somewhere

I did this by selecting the output text with my mouse. Then, to copy it:

Click the **PowerShell icon** (in the top-left of the Window) >  **Edit** > **Copy**

Then I pasted it into a text editor.

### Revert the PowerShell Excecution Policy to its original state

Since I rarely use PowerShell and I loosened the Excecution Policy only to run this, one-off, script I am going to revert it back to its orignal state for security.

Determine the current `ExecutionPolicy`:

```
# Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Change the policy to revert it to its original state:

```
# Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

---

So that's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

To find all .svn files, you can use dir. `dir .svn /s` will do it (though it won't break from scanning subdirectories) or you can use Windows Explorer and ask the little doggy to find all .svn files.

or you could download [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/) and use find after all!

Comment: Thanks for that. Since asking the question I have installed MS Powershell and am going through the 'getting started guide'. But I will also take a look at `unxutils` too.